# Responsive design mess

Tags: css, responsive-design

Right when I thought I had it all understood and organized about media queries and responsive design I have started to see some weird behavior in some devices which makes a mess of it.

My intention is to have a set of media queries with which I can have all different devices/resolutions covered. I have seen some articles with examples and started to put them into practice but when testing in a Samsung Galaxy SII mobile they don't seem to work as expected.

To begin width SII is claimed to have a resolution of 480x800. I don't know whether this resolution is for video playing only but when I prepare my designs they seem to fit to 320px width.

I am using javascript screen.width and screen.height properties to check what resolution it is working with and here are my results:

- In native browser I get a 320x450 resolution when loading the page in portrait orientation. However in this same browser if I reload the page in landscape orientation I get 533x235 dimensions. Right here it is weird enough as I would expect to have the same height and width no matter the orientation to be used. Plus, none of them match the claimed device resolution of 480x800.
- If I use Firefox browser I do get 480x800 width screen properties for both landscape and portrait orientations but if I try to fit a 480px width image it does not, as it seems to have just 320px width for real.

Actually, real resolution in all these cases seems to be 320x533.

Anyone has an explanation for this weird behavior?

Any advice to approach it and get the set of media queries to cover all resolutions??

EDIT::::::::::::::

I have tried with viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

and still no success. Actually according to the article in the link given by hexblot "maximum-scale=1" should not aoiv zooming but it does in my device (it may just be for iOS, don't know). I have following css links:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='only screen and (max-width : 320px)' href='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style-xsmall.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width : 479px)' href='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style-small.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width : 767px)' href='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style-medium.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 959px)' href='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style-large.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='only screen and (min-width : 960px)' href='".home_url()."/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style-xlarge.css'>
```

When visiting the site in my device I can check it is using style-xsmall.css (up to 320px width).

Honestly, it looks like its real width is 320px (at least for web browsing) when in portrait orientation and 533px (weird size) when in landscape.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

have you set the viewport via relevant meta tags ? otherwise the screen may be scaled automatically in most mobile devices. Checkout http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

Comment: Thanks hexblot, I have edited my post after putting into practice what it is said in this article, but I did not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happens because of the pixel density, which in this device is 1.5 (480 becomes 320 and 800 becomes 533). The same appears to happen with some iOS devices using pixel density=2 which divides the real density by 2.

I have gotten this info from this link: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml . Hope it is helpful for somebody else.

Thus it seems that, when using javascript screen properties, firefox retrieves the device width/height whereas the native android browser gets the 'converted' sizes.

I still don't understand why, in native browser, different resolutions are shown deppendind on the device orientation.

And finally, doing some quick tests (unfortunatelly I don't have enough time to get to deep conclusions), it seems that both max-device-width and max-width work with coverted sizes (320x533).

Still, considering it all is a little bit of a mess (at least for me) it would be good if anybody else can give some relevant info on how to deal with all this features.

Comment: You shouldn't really bother with screen size or min/max-device-width as a basis for layout. What you care about is the viewport size once computed by the meta viewport or document.documentElement.clientWidth. See this [table](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html) for reference of the dysfunction between browsers.